# Is there a way to follow a Wordpress site by email alerts for new posts?

Tags: email, notifications

It seems that there's no way for me to get an email alert for new content posted on a particular Wordpress site I follow. And strangely I haven't been able to find any information about it around. I'd think this is a very important feature. I can't expect to check the site every day so email is a very natural way for me to know when there's new content out there. Is there really no way if the site owner doesn't set up a newsletter list? I don't even seem to find IFTTT able to do it.

Answer (score 1):

While WordPress has functionality to send emails out of the box, it doesn't come with any newsletter functionality. Significant enough volume of emails is notoriously unreliable on typical cheap hosts anyway.

WordPress does generate RSS feeds by default, it's an extremely popular format and many tools exist to consume or convert it.

See [Feeds](https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Feeds) in Codex.